# How to search in a list for a part of a string and print out the whole string?

Tags: java, eclipse

I made a code which uses one input and store it in a genertic list and then I use another input to compare it with the first input ... If the first input is "Eric 1991" while the second input is just "Eric" so I want to print out all the sequence like this "Erik 1991" .. I used different ways to search in the namebirthday list , I used for loop then I used contains but they seeme do not work ,, Now I use `toLowerCase().contains(x.toLowerCase()`
I am getting error in eclipse in line of `toLowerCase().contains(x.toLowerCase()`
How can I correct that line to run the code???

```
package shapes;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Base {


public static void main(String [] args) {
    ArrayList<String> namebirthday = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String n=sn.nextLine();
//  String k=sn.nextLine();
//  String m=sn.nextLine();

    namebirthday.add(n);
//  namebirthday.add(k);
//  namebirthday.add(m);
    Scanner sb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String x=sb.nextLine();
        if (namebirthday.toLowerCase().contains(x.toLowerCase())){ // The method toLowerCase() is undefined for the type ArrayList<String>

            System.out.println(namebirthday);

        } else {
            System.out.println("x" +"is not found" );

        }
    }


        }
```

Acually I tried to put `if (((String) namebirthday).toLowerCase().contains(x.toLowerCase())){` but eclipse says "Cannot cast from ArrayList to String- The method toLowerCase() is undefined for the type ArrayList"

What to do???
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `foreach` to get the element form your lest and then do your comparison.
If you use `namebirthday.contains` then this will won't work for  input is like `"Eric"`.

**See following code:**

```
for(String currentString : namebirthday){
    if (currentString.toLowerCase().contains(x.toLowerCase())){ 
        System.out.println(currentString );
    } else {
        System.out.println("x" +"is not found" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot cast from ArrayList to String- The method toLowerCase() is
>   undefined for the type ArrayList

```
if (namebirthday.contains(x.toLowerCase())){ 
            System.out.println(x);

        } else {
            System.out.println("x" +"is not found" );

        }
}
```

Comment: `namebirthday.add(n.toLowerCase())`; while adding to list. @Ali

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `toLowerCase()` in on a list. You have to implent yourself the contains method.

```
private static boolean containsIgnoreCase(List<String> nameBrithday, String s) {
    for (String s1 : nameBrithday){
        if ( s1.toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase())){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call toLowerCase() on the array, you have to call it on each of the members of the array:

```
boolean found = false;
for(String nm : namebirthday) {
    if (nm.toLowerCase().contains(x.toLowerCase())) {
        System.out.println(nm);
        found = true;
        // Add a break; here if you only care about the first match
    }
}
if(!found) System.out.println("x" +"is not found" );
```

Answer (score 0):

`namebirthday` is a `List` instance, not a `String` one. If you want to check something on content of this list, you need to get a single element that is a String. I am posting two examples how you can do it (the first one is probably more useful for you):

**Check if the list contains the element**

```
if (namebirthday.contains("Erik 1991")) {
    // Do something
}
```

**Iterate whole list and do the checking on each element**

```
for (String element : namebirthday) {
    if (element.equals("Erik 1991")) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code

```
package shapes;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Base {


public static void main(String [] args) {
    ArrayList<String> namebirthday = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String n=sn.nextLine();
//  String k=sn.nextLine();
//  String m=sn.nextLine();

    namebirthday.add(n);
//  namebirthday.add(k);
//  namebirthday.add(m);
    Scanner sb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String x=sb.nextLine();
    for (String str : namebirthday){
        if (str.toLowerCase().contains(x.toLowerCase())){
            System.out.println(str);

        } else {
            System.out.println("x" +"is not found" );

        }
      }
     }
    }
```